# Cat files that do not match pattern in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to cat files that do not match the following pattern in hadoop HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -cat /*.gz
```

How do I cat all files that do not end with .gz?

Edit: Sorry but I need to cat files in Hadoop, apparently hdfs comes with very less commands.

Edit 2: All the files are in root.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -not -name '*.gz' -exec cat {} +`

Comment: Or an [extended glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504377/bash-script-does-not-interpret-logical-not-in-glob-expression)

Comment: what do you mean by `/*.gz` ? does `/a/b/c.gz` match?

Comment: bash, or sh, **specifically**? There are bash-only features (like @teapot418 mentioned) that sh can't use; you should tag for one or the other, so we know what's in-bounds.

Comment: how do you define "file"? is a symlink a file? what about pipes/devices/special files (eg `/proc/cpuinfo`)?

Comment: @anubhava, ...well, probably `find / -maxdepth 1 -type f '!' -name '*.gz' -exec cat -- {} +` since the OP is using `/` and a nonrecursive glob.

Comment: To ignore particular extension for globbing try: `GLOBIGNORE='*.gz'`

Comment: Are the `.gz` files you want all in the "root" directory, or do you need to recurse directories? Are you running that command in a shell that may be attempting to expand the glob `*` _before_ hdfs even gets to see it? If so, try single-quoting the glob as `'/*.gz'`

Comment: @Brian61354270 single-quoting the glob works.

Comment: All the files are in root

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs` does not appear to support extended globbing syntax, so you'll need to extract the names of the files you want to concatenate manually.

You can start by [listing all of the files in the root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21569172/11082165) with

```
$ hdfs dfs -stat '%n" '/*'
```

Then, filter out the files ending with `.gz`:

```
$ hdfs dfs -stat '%n" '/*' | grep -v '.gz$'
```

and finally, pass the filtered file names to `hdfs dfs -cat`

```
$ hdfs dfs -stat '%n" '/*' | grep -v '.gz$' | xargs hdfs dfs -cat
```

Note that this may break if the total length of the file paths you pass to `hdfs dfs -cat` exceeds the [limits supported by your environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5772156/11082165).

Comment: This works but gives error for cases where all files end with gz.

Comment: @UtkarshGoel You'll have to tell us the error